# How to get display name from created by field in sharepoint client object model?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, caml, sharepoint-clientobject

In my sharepoint javascript code, I am retrieving items from a list. I used a camel query to download specific fields. One of the fields was `created by` (person who created the item). When I loop through the items, I get the value of the created by field, and if I try to insert it into the dom, it says `[object Object]`.

So I think there is a method I need to call on that object how I don't know what it is... I just want to get the display name from it as a string.

Does anyone know how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, you need to use this method `.get_lookupValue()`.